# encode base64 svg file to path d attribute

Tags: svg, path, base64

I have svg file base64 code, example, `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iQ2FwYV8...`
I want to convert this svg file using path method, example, `<path d="114.939 0H10.449C4.678 .."`

There is any converter or trick how can I do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone is wondering I found answer to my own question.
Source link is https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/converting-an-svg-path-to-a-base64-data-uri-string/278874/7

Easiest solution:

1. copy base64 string
2. paste string into browser address bar
3. browser will generate svg file
4. check browser source and you will see `path d=".."` information.